# New Flutter project runs in command line but not VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I have recently reinstalled Flutter, Android SDK and VSCode.
I start the AVD emulator successfully.
I run Flutter Doctor from the Command line successfully.
I run Flutter create successfully.
I run Flutter run successfully, the basic App runs on the MyEm emulator.
I then open VSCode and at Line 43 there is an error
Invalid override.

```
The type of 'MyHomePage.createState' ('() → _MyHomePageState') isn't a subtype of 'StatefulWidget.createState' ('() → State<StatefulWidget>')
```

Can anyone help explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please post the code that causes this error

Comment: The code is the standard App created by Flutter Create

Comment: Please post the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

I would better recommend you take a look on this link to [create your first flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive)

and this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab)

I was having trouble to create my first app and it helped me to create my first flutter app.